# (Py)OpenCL modify value from all threads simultanously

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

Simple, I have the following kernel which modifies the value of `C[0]`, where `C` is an array with only one element.

```
__kernel void sigma(__global float *A, __global float *B, __global float *C) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    printf("Adding %.2f + %.2f", A[i], B[i]);
    C[0] += A[i] + B[i];
}
```

The problem is, in the end `C[0]` has the value of the thread that finished last, specifically in this example I get the following

```
Adding 1.00 + 0.00
Adding 2.00 + 1.00
Adding 3.00 + 1.00
Adding 4.00 + 1.00
[5.]
```

In the end `C[0]` is `4.00 + 1.00`. What i want is for `C[0]` to be `(1.00 + 0.00) + (2.00 + 1.00) + (3.00 + 1.00) + (4.00 + 1.00)`. So I want each thread's `A[i]` and `B[i]` to be added to `C[0]`.

Also I am not just looking for addition, I want this to be compatible with any function or operation.

This **may be redundant** but in the host code I am just doing the bare minimum to pass in the data to the kernel. Is this problem concenred with the host code?

```
import pyopencl as cl, numpy as np; 
ctx = cl.create_some_context(); queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx); mf = cl.mem_flags
M = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]).astype(np.float32) # A
V = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1]).astype(np.float32) # B
a = np.array([0]).astype(np.float32) # C
# Transfer data to GPU
A_GPU = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=M) 
B_GPU = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=V)
C_GPU = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a.nbytes)
c = np.zeros(shape=a.shape, dtype= np.float32) # array to copy the result
kernel.sigma(queue, M.shape, None, A_GPU, B_GPU, C_GPU)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, c, C_GPU).wait()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to perform reduction in PyOpenCl as  @Elad Maimoni said, is to use the function `work_group_reduce_add` available in version `2.0`.

In python it can be implemented like this

- the kernel

```
kernel = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void resum(__global float *A, __global float *B, __global float *a) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    a[0] = work_group_reduce_add(A[i] + B[i]);
}
""").build(options='-cl-std=CL2.0') # Build using cl 2.0
```

- the rest of the host code

```
# Some example arrays
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
c = np.array([0])
d = np.array([0])

# Create GPU data
a = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
b = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b)
c = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=c)

kernel.resum(queue, (10, ), None, a, b, c)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, d, c)
print(d)
```

This would output `[90]`.

Answer (score 0):

The way your kernel is written is inefficient and can cause non deterministic results in many cases. Generally, you should avoid having multiple threads (work-items) writing to the same address simultaneously. In your case `C[0] += A[i] + B[i];` is a *read modify write* sequence which makes things even worse from a point of view of parallel access.

What you need to use is the **parallel reduction** pattern.
This pattern allows you to efficiently and deterministically sum all elements in the array to a single value (or in your case - 2 arrays). It also support many other associative operators other than addition.

There are many resources online that you can adjust to your case.